# how to add filter in python logging config file (logging.conf)

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to add/use filter in **logging config file**? 
For example, is there any equivalent setting for the following code?

```
import logging

# Set up loggers and handlers.
# ...

    class LevelFilter(logging.Filter):
        def __init__(self, level):
            self.level = level

        def filter(self, record):
            return record.levelno == self.level

    logFileHandler.addFilter(LevelFilter(logging.DEBUG))
```

for handler in logging.conf

```
[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=format_01
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

Can we write logging filter in config file (logging.conf) for above python code as for handler? (The python code is just for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logging with filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters)

Comment: @AbijithMg  This is not duplicate, I am giving this code as example. May be my question is not clear. My question is that, "Is it possible to use filter in logging config file (logging.conf) as handler".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching, I found the answer in official docs which says

> [For example, you cannot configure Filter objects, which provide for
>   filtering of messages beyond simple integer levels, using
>   fileConfig(). If you need to have instances of Filter in your logging
>   configuration, you will need to use dictConfig().](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html)

The logging.conf format is

```
[loggers]
keys=root,log02,log03,log04,log05,log06,log07

[handlers]
keys=hand01,hand02,hand03,hand04,hand05,hand06,hand07,hand08,hand09

[formatters]
keys=form01,form02,form03,form04,form05,form06,form07,form08,form09
```

There is **no config for filter** such as below

```
[filters]
keys=filter01,filter02
```

Answer (score 6):

I did an example in Json if you want. Should be easily possible to switch to your format by following the logic :)

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": true,
  "filters": {
    "skipDebug": {
      "()": "__main__.RemoveLevelFilter",
      "levelToSkip": "DEBUG"
    }
  },
  "formatters": {
    "simple": {
      "format": "%(asctime)s|%(name)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s"
    }
  },
  "handlers": {
    "console":{
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
      "formatter": "simple",
      "stream" : "ext://sys.stdout"
    },
    "file": {
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
      "maxBytes": 5242880,
      "backupCount": 3,
      "formatter": "simple",
      "filename": "log.log",
      "mode": "a",
      "encoding": "utf-8",
      "filters": ["skipDebug"]
    }
  },
  "loggers": { },
  "root": {
    "handlers": ["console", "file"],
    "level": "DEBUG"
  }
}
```

And when you initialize your logger something like:

```
class RemoveLevelFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, levelToSkip):
        self.level = levelToSkip

    def filter(self, record):
        return self.getLogLevelName(record.levelno) != self.level
    enter code here
    def getLogLevelName(self, levelno):
        switcher = {
            10: "DEBUG",
            20: "INFO",
            30: "WARNING",
            40: "ERROR",
            50: "CRITICAL"
        }
        return switcher.get(levelno, "INVALID")

with open("logging.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(fd))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.warning('This is a warning message')
logger.error('This is an error message')
logger.critical('This is a critical message')
```

P.S.: Strange my code like that I know. It was for something a little bit more complex that I truncated.

References:

- [install filter on logging level in python using dictConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455515/install-filter-on-logging-level-in-python-using-dictconfig)