# How to use .yaml file for logging specific level only

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I am dealing with the same problem as [python logging specific level only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8162419/1772898) & [logging with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/879732/1772898) the only exception being i am using an .yaml file.

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html), it says:

> The fileConfig() API is older than the dictConfig() API and does not
> provide functionality to cover certain aspects of logging. For
> example, you cannot configure Filter objects, which provide for
> filtering of messages beyond simple integer levels, using
> fileConfig(). If you need to have instances of Filter in your logging
> configuration, you will need to use dictConfig(). Note that future
> enhancements to configuration functionality will be added to
> dictConfig(), so it’s worth considering transitioning to this newer
> API when it’s convenient to do so.

I have checked [install filter on logging level in python using dictConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21455515/1772898) and [Where is a complete example of logging.config.dictConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7507825/1772898)

My latest python file looks like:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

with open('logging.yaml', 'rt') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
logging.config.dictConfig(config)

logger = logging.getLogger('module1')

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

The `logging.yaml` file looks like:

```
version: 1
formatters:
   simple:
     format: '{asctime} : {name} : {levelname} : {message}'
     style: '{'
handlers:
 console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
   module1:
     level: DEBUG
     handlers: [console]
     propogate: no
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
```

Not understanding how to modify `logging.yaml` file so that I can view only INFO in console and save CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING to `logfile.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here.

I was hoping that I would be able to configure the filter by just modifying `logging.yaml` file. Unfortunately I had to create classes for filtering (in my case `infoFilter` and `criticalFilter`).

The following code log INFO in terminal and WARNING, ERROR or CRITICAL in file.

The Python Code:

```
import logging
import os
import logging.config
import yaml

DEFAULT_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG

class infoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, log_record):
        return log_record.levelno == logging.INFO

class warningerrorcriticalFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, log_record):

        if log_record.levelno in {logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL}:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def log_setup(log_cfg_path='config.yaml'):
    if os.path.exists(log_cfg_path):
        with open(log_cfg_path, 'r') as f:
            try:
                config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
                logging.config.dictConfig(config)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error with file, using Default logging')
                logging.basicConfig(level=DEFAULT_LEVEL)

    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=DEFAULT_LEVEL)
        print('Config file not found, using Default logging')

log_setup()

logger = logging.getLogger('dev')
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error("error message")
logger.critical('critical message')
```

The `config.yaml` file:

```
version: 1

formatters:
  extended:
    format: '%(asctime)-20s :: %(levelname)-8s :: [%(process)d]%(processName)s :: %(threadName)s[%(thread)d] :: %(pathname)s :: %(lineno)d :: %(message)s'
  simple:
    format: "%(asctime)s :: %(name)s :: %(message)s"

filters:
  show_only_info:
    (): __main__.infoFilter
  show_only_warningerrorcritical:
    (): __main__.warningerrorcriticalFilter

handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
    filters: [show_only_info]

  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: my_app.log
    formatter: extended
    level: DEBUG
    filters: [show_only_warningerrorcritical]

loggers:
  dev:
    handlers: [console, file_handler]
    propagate: false
  prod:
    handlers: [file_handler]

root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to create your own filter.

Attempting to set the level to `INFO`, will show `INFO` and above. There is no filter in the logging module that allows you to filter out only a specific level.

Luckily for you, filters can be easily created, as their only requirements are to be a `Filter` object, or any callable returning a boolean value.

In your case, to your console handler, add the following filter:

`handler.addFilter(lambda record: record.levelname == "INFO")`

Comment: I think we have to use `dictConfig` instead of `fileConfig`. Updated the question.

Comment: You can use user defined objects with `dictConfig` if you don't want to mix use both "dict config" and "script config": https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects

Comment: @blueray still doesn't matter. You'll need a custom filter that takes out only info. You're welcome to create a class and use a yaml config.